# Is there any book about topic modelling in machine learning for math student?

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, machine-learning

There are many books introduced in [What is a good book for math students to learn machine learning in depth?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1857677/157643), but after skimming these 2 free books

- Rostamizadeh, Talwalkar, Mohri, [Foundations of Machine Learning](https://mitpress.ublish.com/ebook/foundations-of-machine-learning--2-preview/7093/Cover)
- Shai Shalev-Shwartz and Shai Ben-David, [Understanding Machine Learning: From Theory to Algorithms](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/w%7Eshais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/understanding-machine-learning-theory-algorithms.pdf)

I feel that they don't discuss much about my focus: [topic modelling](https://whatevery1says.github.io/workshops/topic-modeling/slideshow/index.html#/how-topic-modelling-works), or unsupervised learning in general. Do you have any recommendation on this? I've read about projective geometry, groups and representations, complex and dynamic systems, complex analysis, graph theory.

Comment: Because I think of Stack Exchange more as Wikipedia than Reddit. This comments section is a good place to advertise your meta link, though.